# RMarkdown, Centre and reference table in MS Word

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm using R Markdown and am trying to generate a table and centre it in a word document. Below is the code i have taken from [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/bookdown/master/inst/examples/01-components.Rmd) as a test

````
Table \@ref(tab:table-single) is a simple example.

```{r table-single, tidy=FALSE}
knitr::kable(
  head(mtcars, 10), booktabs = TRUE,
  caption = 'A table of the first 10 rows of the mtcars data.'
)
```
````

When i run this piece of code the table name never resolves so i get \@ref(tab:table-single) instead of `Table 2.1` as can be seen from the final [document](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html)

- Can someone see where in my code i have made a mistake in relation to referencing my table

I am knitting to MS Word

Thanks

Comment: Please post one question at a time.

Comment: referencing that way only works for latex output. You can try https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref for other output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [`bookdown`](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown) package to render your markdown, you will get proper cross-referencing:

````
---
output: bookdown::word_document2
---

Table \@ref(tab:table-single) is a simple example.

```{r table-single, tidy=FALSE}
knitr::kable(
  head(mtcars, 10), booktabs = TRUE,
  caption = 'A table of the first 10 rows of the mtcars data.'
)
```
````

[image]